# NodeJS app crashes when I convert some images with ImageMagick: { [Error: Command failed: ] code: null, signal: 'SIGKILL' }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, imagemagick

I have a NodeJS app with MongoDB in a small VPS (1core 64bits, 1GB RAM). The app is a control panel for upload images. After a upload, I generate 4 thumbnails from a image. I'm using [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) for image manipulations with the ImageMagick library.

When I upload 2 or 3 images, the app runs without issues. But when I upload 5 or more, **the app crashes and MongoDB also stops sometimes**. The error showed in terminal:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: ] code: null, signal: 'SIGKILL' }
```

Also, I have noticed that ImageMagick is slow. It takes 4 seconds aprox for a resize.

Is the hardware insufficient? In localhost I never had these problems.

NodeJS version:

```
v0.10.25
```

ImageMagick version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-3 Q16 x86_64 2015-01-14 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma openexr png tiff x xml zlib
```

MongoDB version:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
```

Comment: Terribly hard to answer. Try to increase the RAM and see if the problem persists. `SIGKILL` sounds like the process was terminated on purpose, maybe the VPS has RAM over commit or something similar. Most OSs don't like to be short on RAM *at all*, and some virtualization techs don't make that better.

Comment: I changed to other VPS with a different virtualization tech (before OpenVZ, now VMware) and the issues disappeared.